# How to combine two string in PHP?

Tags: php, string

My PHP Code:

```
$username="jack";
$var= mt_rand(1000,100000 );
$data="$username _Deleted_$var";
echo $data;
```

**Expected Output:** `jack_Deleted_91111` 
**Original Output:** `jack _Deleted_91111`

Comment: Either use `.` or read the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: actually all you need to do is remove your space in your current code between $username and _Deleted

Comment: simple, `$data="$username_Deleted_$var";`

Comment: if you use `"$username_Deleted_$var"`, php will think the variable name is `$username_Deleted_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data = "{$username}_Deleted_$var";`
or
`$data = $username."_Deleted_".$var;`

`.` is in php symbol for concatenating strings, `{ and }` used in string means that anything between this symbol is a variable.

Comment: If it works, will you accept this answer, please? :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data=$username .  '_Deleted_' . $var;
```

See, if that solves your white space issue.

Comment: What output are you getting? Is it saying any error?